# Trigger React onChange event with JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, websocket

I'm trying to update the state in a React component when data is received from a WebSocket connection.

I've created a hidden input form, where when it's changed will trigger the state to update and the component will automatically update based on the data stored inside the state.

I originally tried to trigger the React event with [.change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) which wasn't working, turns out you can't actually trigger React events using jQuery as the events aren't actually proper DOM events. so then I tried actually setting the value of the input to the data sent from the WebSocket, which didn't work either (data can be received every second - sometimes even quicker).

If I set the input to text and start typing, then the component updates correctly. But I need it to update whenever data is received from the server.

Here's my attempt so far:

```
class MyTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data: parsedTradeData };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    console.log("constructed")
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    console.log("changed")
    this.setState({ data: makeData() });
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log("next props")
    console.log(nextProps)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="hidden" className="trade-table-data-input" onChange={ this.handleChange } />
        {this.drawTable()}
      </div>
    );
  }
  drawTable() {
    return React.createElement('div', null, React.createElement(ReactTable, {
            data: this.state.data,
            columns: columns,
            defaultPageSize: 25,
            showPagination: true,
            className: '-striped -highlight table',
            SubComponent: function SubComponent(row) {
                tradeDetailsID = row['row']['id'];

                tradeDetailsConnection = new WebSocket('ws://kieron-pc:8080/request');

                tradeDetailsConnection.onopen = function() {
                    var args = [
                        sessionID,
                        $('#acc_select option:selected').val(),
                        pageID,
                        '15',
                        'TradeDetails',
                        row['row']['id']
                    ];

                    tradeDetailsConnection.send(args.join(','));

                    tradeDetailsConnection.onmessage = function(event) {
                        var dataReceived = event.data.split(',').slice(6).join(',');
                        var requestType = JSON.parse(event.data.split(',')[6] + "}")['id'];

                        data["TradeDetails" + requestType] = dataReceived;
                    }
                }

                return React.createElement("div", { className: "container" }, React.createElement("div", { className: "row" }, React.createElement("div", { className: "col-md-6" }, React.createElement('h5', null, 'Summary'), React.createElement('div', null, React.createElement(ReactTable, {
                            data: makeTradeDetailsSummaryData(row['row']['id']),
                            columns: tradeDetailsSummaryColumns,
                            defaultPageSize: 5,
                            showPagination: false
                        })), React.createElement("h5", null, "Costs"), React.createElement('div', null, React.createElement(ReactTable, {
                            data: makeTradeDetailsCostsData(row['row']['id']),
                            columns: tradeDetailsCostsColumns,
                            defaultPageSize: 4,
                            showPagination: false
                        }))), React.createElement("div", { className: "col-md-6" }, React.createElement("p", null, "chart")), React.createElement("div", { className: "col-md-12" }, React.createElement("h5", null, "Daily Breakdown"), React.createElement("h5", null, "Executions"), React.createElement('div', null, React.createElement(ReactTable, {
                            data: makeTradeDetailsExecutionsData(row['row']['id']),
                            columns: tradeDetailsExecutionsColumns,
                            defaultPageSize: 4,
                            showPagination: false
                        })))));
            },
            defaultSortMethod: function defaultSortMethod(a, b) {
                a = a === null || a === undefined ? '' : a;
                b = b === null || b === undefined ? '' : b;

                if (isNaN(a) && isNaN(b)) {
                    a = a.toLowerCase();
                    b = b.toLowerCase();

                    if (a > b) {
                        return 1;
                    }

                    if (a < b) {
                        return -1;
                    }

                    return 0;
                } else {
                    return a - b;
                }
            },
            getTrProps: function getTdProps(state, rowInfo, column) {
                return {
                    onClick: function onClick(e) {
                        if (expands[rowInfo.index] == true) {
                            expands[rowInfo.index] = false;
                        } else {
                            expands[rowInfo.index] = true;
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        }));
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This code looks too imperative. One of the main React's point is declarativity. You can create elements by `React.createElement` but you should not.

To split up logic and view in your case you can move the "socket code" to a High Order Component (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html).

In it you can make all your socket magic and pass it to wrapped component as props. All changes will be applied automatically.